# best practise when combining standalone tex-files with latxmk

Tags: best-practices, standalone, latexmk

I am currently not sure how to best define my workflow and would like some advice on how to best proceed. Maybe I am just overlooking something obvious.

Assuming the following `tinker.tex` file:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{image.tex}
    \documentclass[margin=1cm]{standalone}
    \begin{document}
        Hello world
    \end{document}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
    \includegraphics{image.pdf}
\end{document}
```

and compiling it with `latexmk -pdf -interaction=nonstopmode tinker.tex` I would expect the image to get created from the existing `image.tex` by running it through a latex compilation step. But this doesn't happen.

The missing file is properly detected (`Latexmk: Missing input file 'image.pdf' [...]`) so I would expect the dependency handeling to jump on it?

Is there a "proper" way to implement this? I have this exact behavior working for `svg` files being converted to pdf via inkscape. This uses a custom dependency and a custom system-call. I expected the latex dependency to already be present or does it need to be defined from the ground up?

---

I like to do this as it makes it easy to work on images/graphics separately until they look right and also have them available as separate files for later use.

I am aware that I could load the `standalone` package in the root document as well and use `\includestandalone` which would even compile the sub-document. This requires passing `-shell-escape` which is potentially unsafe. But more importantly I expected `latexmk` to already be capable of this. So this more aimed at understanding why it's not working and not how to work around it

Comment: I haven't yet tried it myself, but maybe https://ctan.org/pkg/memoize?lang=en could be interesting for you?

Comment: The tcolorbox package also has means to run external documents and include the results.

Comment: Did you check if the svg package can do the conversion for you?

Comment: it can by also calling inkscape from inside the latex run.

Comment: (all of the above approaches will obviously need shell-escape)

Comment: yeah, that what I would like to avoid. I just feel like thats the reason I have a external build system that handles all this

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz `memoize` doesn't require shell escape if you use perl or python extraction. Or rather, it requires only restricted shell escape, which the OP is obviously using already.

Comment: @cfr Oh, that's interesting! Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 2):

You need to define a custom dependency to make a pdf file from a tex file:

```
add_cus_dep( 'tex', 'pdf', 0, 'makeexternaldocument' );
sub makeexternaldocument {
    my ($base_name, $path) = fileparse( $_[0] );
    return system "latexmk", "-output-directory=$path", $_[0];
}
```

Comment: Is `latexmk` able to also check for the existens of a `.latexmkrc` file as part of the dependency-check and call only `pdflatax` if that file is missing or would that be to complicaded and I need to choose one or the other?

Comment: @Cube: I'm sorry, but I don't understand your comment.  On start-up, latexmk checks for the existence of a .latexmkrc file (or files) and runs the code in it. But there's no actual dependency check on the .latexmkrc file. When the code I wrote is in a .latexmkrc it implies that whenever your main document needs a pdf file and a corresponding tex file exists, as in your example, then latexmk will create a dependency between the tex file and the pdf file.  In your case, that implies: (a) The file image.pdf is created if it doesn't exist.  CONTINUED...

Comment: CONTINUATION: (b) If the file image.tex is changed, then an updated image.pdf file is created, and then the main document is recompiled so that the updated image.pdf file is used.

Comment: I will try do clarify: I was asking If I can define dependencies that check more than only the `.tex` and `.pdf` file (more than two files). 
I use GNU make a lot and there constructs like this are possible. I would like to apply different rules depending on the presence of an additional file next to the `.tex` file, but this is probably not possible.

Comment: I am probably just over complicating thing, but I simply have the situation where in my current project the subfile could benefit from beeing build using `latexmk`, but for most of my projects before that it would have sufficed to justs call `pdflatex` directly on the subfile.
I was thinking about a setup that could flexibily adapt to this by detecting the presence of a `.latexmkrc` next to the subfile (which is in a subfolder). But I probably have to live with manual adaptations for each project.

Comment: Then you could replace `latexmk`  by `pdflatex` in the code I wrote.  The advantage of `latexmk` is that if, for example, the tex file used cross references, `latexmk` would do the appropriate number of reruns of `pdflatex`.  It's easier to just use `latexmk` as a matter of course as a convenient replacement for `pdflatex`.

Comment: Don't forget that if it was enough to call `pdflatex` once to get the .pdf file from the .tex file, then you've lost nothing (except a modest amount of CPU time) by replacing the invocation of `pdflatex` by an invocation of `latexmk`.  When the situation gets more complicated, e.g., with cross references in the .tex file, the solution with `latexmk` in the definition of the custom dependency handles that without further changes to the .latexmkrc file.

Comment: As to more complicated dependencies, what to do depends on what the situation is.  I'd suggest looking at the examples in the `example_rcfiles` for ideas that I've found useful.  It's difficult for me to say more without a concrete example of what you actually need to do.